# Как правильно расставить запятые

Tags: запятая

Почувствовать единение с природой можно только пройдя более длинный восьмичасовой маршрут.
 Отдыхая в Хорватии, нужно хоть на один день оторваться от моря и пляжа и приехать сюда.

Answer (score 1):

Все знаки поставлены правильно. Деепричастный оборот в первом предложении не обособляем, так как он начинается с частицы ТОЛЬКО.
Во втором предложении союз И не является повторяющимся, он соединяет однородные члены двух разных рядов: от моря и пляжа; оторваться и приехать. Запятые не нужны.

Comment: Совершенно верно. Согласна с Вами.

Comment: @Верьясова Если Вы согласны с ответом - проголосуйте за него. Это добавит очков автору (что уже приятно) и сделает ответ более заметным (когда появятся другие ответы).